# Sharpdx 2D Camera not moving

Tags: c#, camera, sharpdx

I am trying to move a camera to the right, but it isn't moving.

i use this code to move:

```
Camera.Position.X = gameobject.transform.Position.X;
```

This is the camera code that i use to create Matrix3x2

```
        public Vector2 Position = new Vector2();

    float Rotation = 0;

    public float Zoom = 1;

    public Vector2 ViewportCenter { get { return new Vector2(ViewportWidth * 0.5f, ViewportHeight * 0.5f); } }

    public Matrix3x2 GetTransform3x2()
    {
        return Translation;
    }

    private Matrix3x2 Translation
    {
        get
        {
            return Matrix3x2.Translation(Position) *
                   Matrix3x2.Rotation(Rotation) *
                   Matrix3x2.Scaling(Zoom, Zoom) *
                   Matrix3x2.Translation(ViewportCenter);
        }
    }
```

This is the code that i use to render

```
        public void DrawGameobjects(Gameobject[] gameObjects)
    {
        RawMatrix3x2 CameraPosition = new RawMatrix3x2();

        foreach (Gameobject Gameobject in gameObjects)
        {
            if (Gameobject.Enabeld == true)
            {
                foreach (object Component in Gameobject.Components)
                {
                    //render 2D
                    if (Component is Sprite)
                    {
                        RawMatrix3x2 CurrentTransform = renderTarget.Transform;
                        Sprite NewSprite = Component as Sprite;
                            Bitmap Texture = Game.bitmapManager.GetTexture(NewSprite.texture.TexturePath);
                            RawRectangleF PositionRectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(NewSprite.texture.TextureSize * Zoom)).ToRawRectangleF();
                            float Transparency = NewSprite.Transparency;
                            RawRectangleF ImageRectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(NewSprite.texture.TextureSize * Zoom)).ToRawRectangleF();
                            Vector2 NewScale = (Vector2)Gameobject.transform.Scale;
                            Matrix3x2 Translation = Matrix3x2.Translation((Vector2)Gameobject.transform.Position);
                            Matrix3x2 Rotation = Matrix3x2.Rotation(Gameobject.transform.Rotation.X);
                            Matrix3x2 Scale = Matrix3x2.Scaling((Vector2)Gameobject.transform.Scale);
                            renderTarget.Transform = (Translation * Rotation * Scale).ToRawMatrix3x2();
                            renderTarget.DrawBitmap(Texture, PositionRectangle, Transparency, BitmapInterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor, ImageRectangle);
                            //renderTarget.Transform = CurrentTransform;

                    }

                    if (Component is Camera2D)
                    {
                        CameraPosition = (Component as Camera2D).GetTransform3x2().ToRawMatrix3x2();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        renderTarget.Transform = CameraPosition;

    }
```

Everything moves except the camera

Comment: Are those 3x2 matrices as in 3 columns 2 rows or 3 rows 2 columns? Also, moving requires the last element of the vector to be 1.

Comment: @Bálint it is 3 rows a 2 columns. Also what vector are you talking about when you say the last element of the vector must be 1?

Comment: The vertex's position. Matrix based translation doesn't work by default, because you simply can't add by multiplying. That's why OpenGL sets the 4th element of the vertex position to 1 automatically when you only define 3 coordinates. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=vQ60rFwh2ig

Comment: @Bálint i am only defining 2 coordinates this is 2d, Matrix based translation is working when drawing objects and i tried to make the M32 1 but it still doesn't move. I still don´t what i am doing wrong